# WordPress: auto-update internal links after bulk duplicating posts to new version

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Firstly, I'm sorry if this is duplicate content, but I've searched for a long time and cannot seem to find the appropriate answer for my situation.

Every so often, I need to duplicate all posts (about 250) on my WordPress site to create an updated version for the collective posts. For example, I have 250 posts that are version 2.1, and I'm bulk copying them all to make version 2.2 with the latest updates. I need version 2.1 to remain active for reference (with the associated 2.1 links).

So now I have 250 version 2.1 posts, and another 250 version 2.2 posts.

My issue is that when I duplicate the posts (from 2.1 to 2.2), all of the internal links point to the previous version (2.1) instead of linking to the newly created posts (2.2). I would like to find a way to have all of the links update to the new version either when the new posts are created or done in bulk after the posts are duplicated. Currently, I have to go through every post and update all links manually, which is extremely time consuming.

The links I'm dealing with look like this: https://example.com/?p=12345

Is there any way to get this done in a time-effective manner? Thank you.

I currently use Copy & Delete Posts plugin and change the suffix of the posts to the new version. Then I go back through the new posts and assign categories. After that, I have to manually change all of the internal links in each post.

I'm more than happy to change that entire process if it means the links will update along with the posts.